# python add https:// to url = sys.argv[1]

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm new in Python, how can I add https:// into "url = sys.argv[1]"?

Below is my script, what can I improve from here?

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = sys.argv[1]
username = sys.argv[2]
password = sys.argv[3]

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id("passwd").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id("login").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url = 'https://' + sys.argv[1]
```

If you just want to add `https://` you can just concatenate string by using `+` operator

Best solution is you can check with other condition if url already have `http` as prefix if not then add:

```
url = sys.argv[1]
if((sys.argv[1]).startswith('http')):
    url = 'https://' + sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: Please add more explanation.

Comment: Thank you Yash Jain, is working. If I want to add port no 54321, can I add :54321 add the end like url = 'https://'+ sys.argv[1]':54321' ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do `url = 'https://'+ sys.argv[1]`
if `sys.argv[1]` is google.com url will be `https://google.com`

Best regards

Comment: thank you, is working. If I want to add port no 54321, can I do like url = 'https://'+ sys.argv[1]':54321'

Comment: If you want to add the port to the url you can do it with url = 'https://'+ sys.argv[1] + ':54321' . You can use the + sign to concatenate string in python https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python